# GIMP extended input devices settings problem

Tags: settings, gimp, input-devices, graphics-tablet

I have a Trust graphics tablet. Today I realized how to make GIMP use the tablet's sensitivity features: by going to Edit > Preferences > Input Devices > Configure Extended Input Devices, and there change the settings for the tablet. This works fine, until I close GIMP and reopen it. Then no input device is able to do anything and I need to go through the menus again to enable the tablet.

What happens is that there are two entries for extended input devices to the tablet: one for the tablet's stylus, and one for its mouse (not my PS/2 moues, but rather a mouse that arrived packed with the tablet and that is used by it). Whenever I change the settings for the stylus entry, it works, but when I quit GIMP and reenter, it somehow transfers the settings I used for the stylus to the second entry: that of the mouse.

It's probably because GIMP recognizes the two input devices with the same name (I can see two "UC-LOGIC Tablet WP8060U" entries in the settings dialog) and somehow it attributes the settings I made to the mouse before it does to the stylus. Maybe if I change the name of one input device it will work properly? How do I do that? And if that doesn't work, what else can I try?

EDIT: After reading a little, I tried tinkering with the options found in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d, but I only managed to make The X server ignore the stylus instance of the tablet and not the mouse instance. I don't understand how that's possible, as I went through everything in the driver that activates the tablet and disabled it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Save input device settings on exit" right on the "Input Devices" tab in the Preferences dialog. Use it :)

Comment: Yes, it was enabled, but the problem was that it saved the settings on the wrong input device, i.e., the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like

```
Section "InputClass"
     MatchUSBID "5543:0005"
     MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
     Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

Which should ignore just the mouse interface, you can replace the USBID with the correct one, but I believe that is the correct one for the WP8060. Hopefully that helps.